# How to access the `polymorphic` base class for any child of an `std::variant`?

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism, c++17, variant

Let suppose several child classes for a base class:

```
class Base 
{
public:
    void printHello() const { cout << "Hello" << endl; }
};

class Child1: public Base {};
class Child2: public Base {};
class Child3: public Base {};
..
class ChildN: public Base {};
```

Let suppose a variant containing any of the contained classes:

```
using MyVariant = std::variant<Base, Child1, Child2, Child3, ... ChildN>;
```

> **Note:** The interest of this (compared to a simple vector of polymorphic
>   pointers), is to have all the data in the same memory array, because
>   they are going to be transferred to a device. In this case, the real
>   content of each object is in the vector, not only a pointer to some
>   `heap` position.

Finally, let suppose I want to work with the `Base` polymorphic version of each element of a `vector<MyVariant>`.

```
std::vector<MyVariant> myVariantList;
... // Initialization

for (const MyVariant& elem: myVariantList)
{
    const Base* baseElem = get_if_polymorph<Base>(elem); //HOW TO?
    baseElem->printHello();
}
```

> **Note:** Obviously, the trivial solution of having an `if` statement for each types is **not** the intention, because new child classes could be added to `MyVariant` without having to change all further usages. (Extensibility)

So another way to express the question is:

**How to manage polymorphism within std::variant?**

Comment: Really good question.  Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `std::visit` with a generic lambda:

```
const Base& baseElem = std::visit(
    [](const auto& x) -> const Base& { return x; },
    elem);
```

---

Minimal reproducible example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <variant>
#include <vector>

struct Base {
    virtual void hi() const
    {
        std::cout << "Base\n";
    }
};

struct Derived1 : Base {
    void hi() const override
    {
        std::cout << "Derived1\n";
    }
};

struct Derived2 : Base {
    void hi() const override
    {
        std::cout << "Derived2\n";
    }
};

int main()
{
    using Var = std::variant<Base, Derived1, Derived2>;
    std::vector<Var> elems;
    elems.emplace_back(std::in_place_type<Base>);
    elems.emplace_back(std::in_place_type<Derived1>);
    elems.emplace_back(std::in_place_type<Derived2>);
    for (const auto& elem : elems) {
        const Base& x = std::visit(
            [](const auto& x) -> const Base& { return x; },
            elem);
        x.hi();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Base
Derived1
Derived2
```

([live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/SR7jug2VrUkeZgwR))